# Count sub-label based on label

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

In my Angular 9 project, I want to split an array based on `lable`, then inside the array, I want to take count based on `subLable`.

This is my array:

```
[
    {"id":1,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Application","subLable":"Nice"},
    {"id":2,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Channels","subLable":"Quality"},
    {"id":3,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Application","subLable":"poor"},
    {"id":4,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Application","subLable":"Nice"}
]
```

Here **`lable`: Application** comes 3 times and **`lable`: Channels** comes 1 time. Here, I want to split the array based on the `lable` like this:

```
Application[
    {"id":1,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Application","subLable":"Nice"},    
    {"id":3,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Application","subLable":"poor"},
    {"id":4,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Application","subLable":"Nice"}
]
    
Channels[
    {"id":2,"socialMediaId":0,"accountId":1,"lable":"Channels","subLable":"Quality"},
]
```

For the same value in `subLable` take into count, so the final result will come like this:

```
Application subLable Nice count 2, poor count 1
```

I tried this code:

```
this.smdashboardservice.fetchSmDashboardData().subscribe(response=>{
  const lable = response.data.reduce((acc, v) => {
    acc[v.lable] = acc[v.lable] || [];
    acc[v.lable].push(v);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  console.log(lable)
})
```

Current result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Your question is unclear. what is the expected result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost similar to how you group by `lable`. Within the `lable` property, there will be an object (key-value pair) with `subLable` as key and an array as  value.

```
const lable = input.reduce((acc, v) => {
    acc[v.lable] = acc[v.lable] || {};

    acc[v.lable][v.subLable] = acc[v.lable][v.subLable] || [];
    acc[v.lable][v.subLable].push(v);

    return acc;
}, {} as { [key:string]: { [key:string]: any[] } });
```

As a result, the output will be:

```
{
  "Application": {
    "Nice": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "socialMediaId": 0,
        "accountId": 1,
        "lable": "Application",
        "subLable": "Nice"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "socialMediaId": 0,
        "accountId": 1,
        "lable": "Application",
        "subLable": "Nice"
      }
    ],
    "poor": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "socialMediaId": 0,
        "accountId": 1,
        "lable": "Application",
        "subLable": "poor"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Channels": {
    "Quality": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "socialMediaId": 0,
        "accountId": 1,
        "lable": "Channels",
        "subLable": "Quality"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Next, use the `for...in` loop to iterate the key of `lable` object. And another `for...in` loop to iterate the key of `lable[k]` object.

```
for (let k in lable) {
    let msg = `${k} subLable `;

    for (let subK in lable[k]) {
        msg += `${subK} count ${lable[k][subK].length} `;
    }

    console.log(msg.trim());
}
```

[Demo @ TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)